# Can you tilt, skew, or change perspective using Greensock?

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to tween programmatically an image using greensock, but i dont know if it is possible to make it look like the image is 3d.

kind of like flash's 3d functionality.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can tween any property using TweenLite/Max. So you could do something like this:

```
TweenLite.to(mc, 1, {x:65, y:117, z:-80, rotationY:50, rotationX:-74});
```

Just have a go at tweening any properties you see this the [as3 docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#propertySummary).